# Usage of "as such"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

I read that this sentence is incorrect:

> Because of the accident, he arrived at the dock an hour late. As such, he missed the boat and forfeited his deposit.

Why is it wrong? What is the correct usage of "as such"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As such* means "by virtue of being such" or "in such a capacity":

> He is a Justice of the Peace. As such, he is empowered to perform marriages.

*Such* refers to the preceding noun phrase *Justice of the Peace* and *as such* applies to the following noun phrase *he*.

> As a Justice of the Peace, he is empowered to perform marriages.
>   In his capacity of Justice of the Peace he is empowered to perform marriages.

In your example, *as such* is taken to modify *he*; but in what capacity, or by virtue of being what did he miss the boat? There is no preceding noun phrase to which *such* may refer.

And even if you rewrite the clause as a noun phrase: *The accident caused his arrival an hour late*, the noun phrase *arrival an hour late* is not a role or an office *by virtue of which* he missed the boat, it is the cause of his missing the boat.

What is meant is *in consequence* or *as a result*—implicitly, *in consequence **of that*** or *as a result **of that***, where *that* has its referent the entire preceding clause— phrases which modify the entire following clause and not just *he*.

Comment: Can _as such_ be used at the beginning of a sentence, if the previous sentence is "He was late."?

Comment: @kiamlaluno No. *As such* ≠ *As he was late*; *as* is a preposition in this construction, not a conjunction, and *such* is a pronoun which must refer to a nominal. OK: *He was marked as a latecomer. As such, he received only partial credit for attendance.*